# How to display many pictures on form?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

how to display several pictures at once on some form, which are stored in a table ir_attachment ?

```
class Characteristic(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"

    image_1 = fields.Many2many('ir.attachment', string="Image")
```

Comment: What lib do you work with?

Comment: Xyndra, What is lib? Odoo-12